# Accessing Variables within a Function Without Using Return

Tags: ios, swift, function

**I have a function within an extension, and I'm trying to access a variable that exists within it. The code is as follows:**

```
extension MyCell: YSSegmentedControlDelegate {
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {
    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index
    print(tagToIndex)

}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}
}
```

**Where `tagToIndex` is the variable I am trying to access**. While the function returns `void` right now, I was able to get it to return `tagToIndex` by declaring a return type of dictionary. However, since you can't return a value without feeding parameters into a function (and I can't do this, given that these parameters are fed by YSSegmentedControl), `return` doesn't really work.

I thought about maybe using closures, but this method sounds a little bit weird to me. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: you can use delegates - that's what you're already doing in fact, with `didPressItemAt`, but you can set up a new delegate function and use that to pass `tagToIndex`

Comment: `tagToIndex` must be a property of your object, so you can access it on any method.